# Unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection timed out)

Tags: xcode, ssl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pem

I'm going crazy with Apple push notification!
I've developed my app and test notifications following [Ray Wanderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) tutorial and everything worked fine until I changed the file .pem with the distribution one and changed the connection string from gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com to gateway.push-apple.com.

Now if I try to send a message the server returns

```
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to     ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection timed out)
Failed to connect: 110 Connection timed out
```

The php file and the .pem file are on a TMDHosting: I try to ask them if port number 2195 is closed because googling I found that the error means port is closed.

Though, I can't understand if the error is linked to the certificate or to the server.

The strange things is that if I follow the procedure with the Terminal to test the .pem file , everything seems to work

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
    depth=1 /C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c)     2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
    verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
    verify return:0
    ---
    Certificate chain
     0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc/OU=Internet     Services/CN=gateway.push.apple.com
       i:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c)     2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
     1 s:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c)     2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
       i:/O=Entrust.net/OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.)/OU=(c)     1999 Entrust.net Limited/CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    MIIEXTCC..........
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
    subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc/OU=Internet         Services/CN=gateway.push.apple.com
    issuer=/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c)      2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
    ---
    No client certificate CA names sent
    ---
    SSL handshake has read 2541 bytes and written 2039 bytes
    ---
    New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
    Server public key is 1024 bit
    Secure Renegotiation IS supported
   Compression: NONE
   Expansion: NONE
    SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
        Session-ID: 
        Session-ID-ctx: 
        Master-Key:     CBA98981BB512ED2FDF0C003F4556FDDA564BEBBEFC6528C37D8E0336BC141AEC6D7E014568B334B8330FFFE266E8CB4
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1332945845
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

This lets me to think that it's not a .pem problem...

Am I wrong?

I've already read all the similar question here, and tried to change the port number from 2195 to 30, but nothing changes.
Hints?

**EDIT**: I found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444355/iphone-push-notification-unable-to-connect-to-the-ssl-server) and seems equal to my problem: TMDHosting told me

> ...you are located under a shared hosting environment and opening a
>   port for you will be not possible. However note that the address to
>   which you are making a connection on port 2195 is not associate with
>   our server. In other words you are trying to make a connection to a
>   remote server on port 2195. In order to make this connection to the
>   port specified above you should make sure that the port is opened for
>   incoming connections on the remote server and not on the server on
>   which your account with us relies.

Do I need a VPS?

**EDIT2**:

In the tutorial I followed I found

> .. you will need a server that is connected to the internet. Push
>   notifications are always sent by a server. For development you can use
>   your Mac as the server (which we’ll do in this tutorial) but for
>   production use, you need at least something like a VPS (Virtual
>   Private Server). A cheap shared hosting account is not good enough.
>   You need to be able to run a background process on the server, install
>   an SSL certificate, and be able to make outgoing TLS connections on
>   certain ports. Most shared hosting providers do not let you do this,
>   although they might if you ask. However, I really recommend using a
>   VPS host such as Linode.

At last I think I do need a VPS. Can you confirm for sure?
**But why if I send push notification with the sandbox server it works properly without VPS?**

***LAST UPDATE***: (hope to help someone) it seems like there was a bug because the right thing is that I cannot send push notification not to the sandbox nor to the production server from my  hosting (TMDHosting): my shared hosting has not the 2195 port open. Changed provider: everything works.

Comment: by the end, What's Provider that you used?, I have the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Miwi,

Thanks for this detailed writeup.

We are having a similar issue and it is driving us nuts.

When we test the cert, it appears to work, other than:
"verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate"

Regardless, we get a valid handshake with the command line test of openssl, just as you do.

We can get the sandbox/dev cert to work as well.

Can you let us know what provider you switched to just in case we need to make the switch?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm Italian: I asked them: http://www.devise.it/en for a domain (with a dedicated ip address). I don't know if they can help you,in any case I found, by googling, lots of providers where you can register a domain with the 2195 port open. See here too "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593820/what-is-the-best-host-provider-for-apple-push-notification-service". Hope that helps!