# Apple Push with proxy and stream_context

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications, http-proxy

I have to send push notification to iOS devices. My connection has to be enabled through a proxy. I tried everything but without success. I have an error 110 Connection Timed Out. It's working with cURL if I just try to connect to Apple push's address. I don't know where the problem is. Proxy config ? PHP stream_context wrong implementation ?

Here's my code :

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'certificate.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'my_passphrase');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'http', 'proxy', 'tcp://my-proxy.net:8080');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'http', 'request_fulluri', true);

$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
var_dump($fp);
var_dump($err);
var_dump($errstr);
exit;
```

Do you have an idea ?

**EDIT:**

Can it be directly linked to Squid ? I just figured out the proxy is running with Squid.
I also try with `fopen()` function instead of `stream_socket_client()` but it seems it doesn't allow  ssl protocol.

Here's my var_dump outputs : *bool(false) int(110) string(20) "Connection timed out"*

I also have this warning : Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection timed out) in /share/www/website/test.php on line 22

Comment: Could we see those var_dump outputs please?

Comment: @EduárdMoldován yes it's done

Comment: Any help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372308/apns-ssl-gateway-sandbox-push-apple-com2195-connection-fails? Is there any chance of your isp blocking the port? Or your own router?

Comment: Try this one: telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195

Comment: The answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154235/using-charles-and-ssl-apple-push-address says, that setting the proxy for `http` does not apply to `ssl://` maybe that is the reason for your problem.

Comment: @BjörnKaiser yes I know but all example for proxy are using http key for stream_context_set_option.

Comment: @Pierre Sorry, haven't seen you asked this question :D

Comment: @BjörnKaiser :D I'm so f*** blocked with this problem

Comment: Really dumb question - is allow_url_fopen enabled ?http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: @Danack yes I've already checked

Comment: I think the only thing left I can recommend in using TCPDump to inspect the network packets leaving your server, and seeing if they go to your proxy correctly.

If they are then it must be the proxy that is the issue. If the packets aren't leaving your box then it would be an issue with your server.

If you're going to view the dumps in Wireshark then the command for tcpdump would be:
tcpdump -i <interface> -s 65535 -w <some-file>

Comment: So was it the proxy just not allowing it?

Comment: Have a look at my reply in this post: [Send Push Notification to APNS through proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450511/send-push-notification-to-apns-through-proxy/32978293#32978293)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could simply be your proxy does not allow port 2195 to be opened.

[iPhone Push Notification Unable to Connect to the SSL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444355/iphone-push-notification-unable-to-connect-to-the-ssl-server)

I guess you either:

- Need to talk to the people who run the proxy to see if port 2195 is open or not.

or

- Setup a test server listening on port 2195 and then try to do a test connection to it through the proxy. That should allow you to test if it is the proxy that is blocking the connection requests.

or

- Test whether Curl can open the connection using a proxy.

Which is done by setting the options:

```
// sets the proxy to go through
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
// sets to use a tunnel proxy which most http proxies are
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPTUNNELPROXY, $proxy);
```

Full testing code [here](http://www.oooff.com/php-affiliate-seo-blog/php-automation-coding/easy-php-proxy-checker-writing-tutorial/).

Comment: No, ports 2195 and 2196 are open. If I use fopen() I can log an Apple connection through https

Comment: Just to check, you mean something like this works? i.e. fopen with the context you've created?

fopen('http://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', "r", false, $ctx );

Comment: Hum no I have : "failed to open stream"

Comment: So even fopen() fails when going through the proxy? It does sound like the proxy is the problem. I added a curl test, which should be the ultimate test of whether the proxy is working or not.

Comment: If I do it using cURL (with https://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 and my certificate) i have : " Empty reply from server" code 52

Comment: And what about fsockopen function with proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

- create the SSL context
- open a tcp socket to the proxy
- send request to the proxy to connect to APNs
- once connexion is accepted enable SSL

Have a look at my reply in this post: [Send Push Notification to APNS through proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450511/send-push-notification-to-apns-through-proxy/32978293#32978293)