# Using Charles and SSL Apple push address

Tags: php, ios, proxy, push-notification, charles-proxy

I have to confirm that my PHP code for sending push notification is working with a proxy. I installed Charles and I'm able to watch all my web traffic through a proxy (127.0.0.1:8888).

Now I would like to see if my script is correctly working for push notifications.
I have :

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'http', 'proxy', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8888');
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
```

I'm getting my push notification but I can't see what is happening in Charles. So my script is not using proxy ...

Do you know why ?

Comment: What the hell do you mean you installed me!?

Comment: @Charles ;) I mean http://www.charlesproxy.com

Comment: Indeed.  So, wild guess here, but do we *know* that the *http* proxy option in the stream context applies to *https* as well?

Comment: @Charles It does apply to `https://`. However, it does *not* apply to `ssl://`. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you passed a context with `http` options to `stream_socket_client()` - and more to the point you used an `ssl://` wrapper instead of `http://` or `https://`.

The `stream_socket_*()` functions do not know that you are implementing HTTP so they do not use the `http` context options - in order for this to work you would need to do e.g.

```
$fp = fopen('https://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195/path/to/file', 'r', false, $ctx);
```

This is probably a better idea anyway, because it is unlikely you would need the granular control that implementing HTTP manually would give you for the Apple APIs.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean but now I have this error : fopen(gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy

Comment: @Pierre Well that sounds like Charles is not set up properly for passing SSL through, which is not something I really know enough about. Does it work if you configure your web browser to use the proxy and try to access a https url? Does Charles log any errors?

Comment: via my browser I can access to https urls (like facebook)

Comment: in my script if I remove my proxy in context i get the same error

Comment: @Pierre Well I must be honest that seems a little unlikely - are you sure it's not being set somewhere else? Or maybe you modified the default stream context?