# Send Push Notification to APNS through proxy

Tags: php, ios, proxy, apple-push-notifications

i've read different question similar to mine, but no answer works for me:

```
$deviceToken = 'token';

$passphrase = 'passphrase';

$message = 'Questa è una notifica!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
$options = array('http' => array('proxy' => 'tcp://proxy.net:8080', 'request_fulluri' => true));

stream_context_create($options);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'cert.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
```

the error is

```
Failed to connect: 110 Connection timed out
```

i've tried to change $option value with:

```
$options = array('ssl' => array('proxy' => 'tcp://proxy.net:8080', 'request_fulluri' => true));
```

but nothing work, the proxy is absolutly minimal and direct connection are not possible.

Any suggestion about something to ask to IT division?

**UPDATE**

port 2195 is open

Comment: Why are you connecting to proxy.net at port 9999? Is there a proxy there? Can you connect to port 9999 from your server?

Comment: no ok the port is 8080, it's only a fake port for the snippet, however i change it

Comment: A typical web proxy often runs on port 8080. You need a transparent proxy (gateway).

Answer (score 2):

If your proxy support CONNECT method you need to connect first to the proxy then ask the proxy to connect you to apns server and finally switch up SSL.

```
$apns_settings = array(
        "host" => 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com',
        "port" => 2195,
        "certificate" => 'ipad.pem',
        "passphrase" => '',
);

$proxy = 'proxyhttp:8080';

$context_options = array(
        'ssl' => array(
                'local_cert' => $apns_settings["certificate"],
                'passphrase' => $apns_settings["passphrase"],
                'peer_name' => $apns_settings["host"],
                'SNI_server_name' => $apns_settings["host"],
        ),
);
$stream_context = stream_context_create($context_options);
// connection to your proxy server
$apns = stream_socket_client('tcp://'.$proxy, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $stream_context);
// destination host and port must be accepted by proxy
$connect_via_proxy = "CONNECT ".$apns_settings["host"].":".$apns_settings["port"]." HTTP/1.1\r\n".
"Host: ".$apns_settings["host"].":".$apns_settings["port"]."\n".
"User-Agent: SimplePush\n".
"Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive\n\n";
fwrite($apns,$connect_via_proxy,strlen($connect_via_proxy));
// read whole response and check successful "HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established"
if($response = fread($apns,1024)) {
        $parts = explode(' ',$response);
        if($parts[1] !== '200') { 
                die('Connection error: '.trim($response));
        } else {
                echo "R:".$response.":R\n";
        }
} else {
        die('Timeout or other error');
}
echo "Proxy opened communication...\n";
// switch to SSL encrypted communication using local certificate from $context_options
if (stream_socket_enable_crypto($apns,true,STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT))
    echo "Switched to SSL OK...\n";
else
    die('some error in SSL negociation');
```

You can after this use the stream as normal.

Have a look at this code here: [Fork of SimplePush.php](https://github.com/flav1972/SimplePush/blob/master/proxypushbatch.php)